# In tensorflow encoder-decoder model like FCN, segnet, how to give arbitrary input size?

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-segmentation

For image semantic segmentation model in tensorflow, I need to give a variable size input to a FCN or segnet model. So I use a placeholer:

```
self.input= tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size,None,None,3),name='')
```

In an encoder-decoder model, I need to unpool after maxpooling, code is like:

```
#upsample fuction used in decoder
def _upsample_along_axis(volume, axis, stride, mode='COPY'):
    shape = volume.get_shape().as_list()
    assert 0 <= axis < len(shape)
    target_shape = shape[:]
    target_shape[axis] *= stride
    padding = tf.zeros(shape, dtype=volume.dtype) if mode == 'ZEROS' else volume
    parts = [volume] + [padding for _ in range(stride - 1)]
    volume = tf.concat(parts, min(axis+1, len(shape)-1))
    target_shape = np.array(target_shape)
    target_shape[0] = -1
    volume = tf.reshape(volume, target_shape)

    return volume
```

Now that target_shape[axis] is none, so `target_shape[axis] *= stride` will raise an error:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'int'

So the input of encoder-decoder model can be variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tensor's `get_shape` function returns inferred shape, and for dynamic dimensions inferred shape is `None`. There is a function in TensorFlow that returns dynamic shape: [`tf.shape`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/shape).

This function returns tensor that will evaluate to actual value of a shape.

Also there are two functions that you may find useful for your case: [`tf.pad`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/pad) and [`tf.tile`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/tile).

Comment: Thanks. Tf.shape() is exactly what I need!!